# Esperar resultado de una funcion para guardar

Tags: nodejs

Como ejecutar una función y esperar resultado para guardar los datos:

tengo

```
if (!_.isUndefined(image)){
    upload(image).then(function(response) {
      if (!response.success)
        return res.status(202).send(upload);

      image = response.image;  
    });
  }

dataProfile.save(function(err, data) {
  return res
      .send({
        success: true,
        data: data
      });
});
```

pero cuando ejecuto, al guardar el valor de image me lo toma undefined o toma un valor anterior porque no se ha terminado de ejecutar la función. ¿Cómo haria para esperar el resultado de la función y guardarlo?

Comment: dentro de `function(response){/*Haz lo que tengas que hacer con response.image*/}`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la librería [Co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) para un mejor manejo de promesas si quieres usar un código de estilo síncrono.

```
co(*() => {
  let response = yield upload(image);
  // hacer algo con la respuesta
}).catch((err) => {

});
```

O si quieres hacer uso del próximo ES8 y sus novedades Async/Await, puedes usar [Babel](https://babel.io) para transpilarlo a ES5. Este es mi método preferido.

```
let response = await upload(image);
// hacer algo con la respuesta
```

Si prefieres las promesas, como lo tienes, primero debes convertir la respuesta a JSON, de esta manera:

```
upload(image)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // aqui data ya es un objeto
  });
```

Ten en cuenta que JavaScript es un lenguaje asíncrono, de tal modo que dentro de un callback no puedes retornar hacia fuera de la función principal.